# Use heroku:config vars locally with Python

Tags: python, heroku, flask, environment-variables

I built a Flask app and have set a set of config vars on heroku. I pulled those locally with [heroku-config](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-foreman-and-heroku-config), so that they reside in the `.env` file in my project's directory.

I use these config vars in Python the standard way, with `os.environ['KEY']`. Everything works like a charm if I run my Flask app with heroku's foreman. But if I try to run through Flask's server, is breaks, since the config vars are not present in my `os.environ` dict.

As this seams obvious, how can I solve this problem? I don't want to manually copy all heroku-pulled config vars to my `~/.bash_profile`. I am more after a way of reusing the heroku-pulled config vars in the `.env`, but I don't know how exactly is the right way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following bash command imports the variables in `.env` into the environment:

```
$ source .env
```

After that you should be able to run your Flask app without Foreman.

Comment: Also consider [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv), which automatically does this for you upon changing to the directory.

Comment: The variables are indeed imported, but I still cannot use them in Python (i.e. opening a Python shell, importing the `os` module and view the `os.environ` dict). What should I do more?